# Connection close when sending post nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, post, postman

controllers: post.js

```
const Post = require('../models/post')
exports.createPost = (req, res) => {
    const post = new Post(req.body)
    console.log("CREATING POST: ", post)
}
```

models: post.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const postSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    title: {
        type: String,
        required: "Title is required",
        minlength: 4,
        maxlength: 150
    },
    body: {
        type: String,
        required: "Body is required",
        minlength: 4,
        maxlength: 2000
    }
})
module.exports = mongoose.model("Post", postSchema)
```

routes: post.js

```
const express = require('express')
const postController = require('../controllers/post')
const router = express.Router()
router.get('/', postController.getPosts)
router.post('/post', postController.createPost)
module.exports = router
```

app.js

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const morgan = require('morgan')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')

const postRoutes = require('./routes/post')

const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const dotenv = require('dotenv')
dotenv.config()

//db connection
mongoose.connect(
    process.env.MONGO_URI,
    {useUnifiedTopology: true,
     useNewUrlParser: true}
)
.then(() => console.log('DB Connected'))

mongoose.connection.on('error', err =>{
    console.log(`DB connection error: ${err.message}`)
})

//middleware
app.use(morgan('dev'))
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use("/", postRoutes)

const port = 8080
app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`A node js API is listening on port ${port}`)
})
```

When I try to send a post with postman I get back 400 Bad request and in header key: Connection, value: close. In the console I get message: POST /post - - ms - -. It doesn't log anything from the application.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Your controller isn't using `res.send()`, `res.render()` or a similar command to send a reply back to the browser. It just logs to the console and does nothing further.

Comment: It doesn't even log into the console

Comment: Can you show us the connectionString, how you have opened the connection, and the server is up after 400 response.

Comment: I updated with code

Comment: use `module.exports.createPost` instead, and then add `res.send()` etc as previous comment said 15hours ago